# Load django template from the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Im trying to render a django template from a database outside of djangos normal request-response structure. But it appears to be non-trivial due to the way django templates are compiled. I want to do something like this:

```
>>> s = Template.objects.get(pk = 123).content
>>> some_method_to_render(s, {'a' : 123, 'b' : 456})
>>> ... the rendered output here ...
```

How do you do this?

Comment: I just wonder how you will be updating your templates? You will be breaking the MVC/T django model framework

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's nothing complicated about this, and it doesn't have anything to do with the request/response structure. All you need to do is pass the template string into the `django.template.Template` constructor (BTW, I've changed the name of your model, to avoid confusion):

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from myapp.models import DbTemplate

s = DbTemplate.objects.get(pk=123).content
tpl = Template(s)
tpl.render(Context(dict(a=123, b=456)))
```

Comment: AFAICT you need to wrap the argument dict in a call to Context() for this to work, ie: `from django.template import Context; tpl.render(Context({'a' : 123, 'b' : 456}))`

Answer (score 10):

There is a reusable app which loads templates from the database:

http://django-dbtemplates.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Seems like it's abandoned, sadly.. Last version in PyPI is from 2012.

Comment: @user1496984 - But over on [GitHub](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates) it's been updated 6 months ago.