# Django: proper way to reload template library

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using custom template tags to show site-specific content. Templates for these tags are stored in database and staff is able to edit them. I used  [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462909/2419628) as reference. Each time after template changed and saved into database, I force reloading of django app (by reloading uwsgi service) or changes doesn't become visible. Looks like Django populates template library for custom tags only on first load of app.
I think reloading Django app isn't best practice to refresh DB templates, and I am searching way to do it programmatically (from model's save() or on save signal)

Template tags code:

```
from django.template import Template, Library
from project.custom_templates.models import DbTemplate

register = Library()

# template names
SHOW_PART_TABLE_ADMIN = 'custom/tags/show_part_table_admin.html'
SHOW_PART_TABLE_PUBLIC = 'custom/tags/show_part_table_public.html'
t_show_part_table_admin = Template(DbTemplate.objects.get(name=SHOW_PART_TABLE_ADMIN).content)
t_show_part_table_public = Template(DbTemplate.objects.get(name=SHOW_PART_TABLE_PUBLIC).content)

@register.inclusion_tag(t_show_part_table_admin)
def show_part_table_admin(parts, user, perms):
    return {'parts': parts, 'user': user, 'perms': perms}
@register.inclusion_tag(t_show_part_table_public)
def show_part_table_public(parts, user, perms):
    return {'parts': parts, 'user': user, 'perms': perms}
```

Comment: I don't get it, if you have template string saved somewhere, why can't you feed the parameters in the view method and render it in the template? What does that have to do with the django template tag?

Comment: @ShangWang that's not just strings but django templates, I want to make them configurable from admin, and able to show different data to different users. For example, I am showing table with additional columns for staff users, and table without them for other users. Of course I can hardcode that in filesystem templates, but I also want to allow flexible changes to them, so I am store them in DB.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://django-dbtemplates.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @ShangWang I saw it, but didn't tried yet, maybe you're right it is better to switch to use that app, instead of making own. Right now way with reloading UWSGI works pretty well, but I afraid that can cause troubles later.

Comment: For sure you would have huge trouble because you are not suppose to restart the web server. If you have many users accessing the resource while people are saving a template every minute, the user experience would be unbearable. You should control your app's behavior like you have break peddle for the car, not turn off the engine every time you stop at the red light :)

Comment: @ShangWang that's why I am looking for the way to do it programmatically, I am looked into sources of django-dbtemplates and looks like Template model refresh cache on save signal. But I don't use any caching for now, and I haven't any caching middlewares enabled. I just try to understand better how Django templates are working

Comment: You should probably show the code for your template tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done