# How to read Jinja from a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I want to store small Django templates in a database and include them in my view. What I need to do is call something like

```
<ul>
    {% for item in foo.items.all %}
     <li>{{ item.snippit }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Where snippet is a string like `this product is made from {{ bar.percent }} &percnt; recycled materials`

I need to know how I would go about rendering this text as Jinja before sending it to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462909/7976758

For more elaborate solution use https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates

Django template loader for database stored templates.

1. It allows you to store templates in your database.
2. It provides template loader that enables Django to load the templates from the database.

Comment: yes, i've seen these before. if i was loading a standalone template, this is something i would do, but what i need is to load Jinja into an existing template dynamically from another string. a good start would just be rendering any jinja passed through the request context

Comment: Jinja has its own [API](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/intro/#basic-api-usage). `from jinja2 import Template` + `template = Template(jinja_tmpl_string)` + `template.render()`. Isn't it enough?

Comment: how can i call template.render from inside another template, though?

Comment: You create a function in your code, pass the function to the template and call the function.

Comment: you can do that?

Comment: I had been calling thousands functions in Jinja (though not in Djanga), what's the problem?