# Django is rendering template from the database efficient

Tags: python, django

This is not a HOWTO question, as it, as such, has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462792/load-django-template-from-the-database)

I am trying to integrate Django with modern frontend framework, and I found that it is possible to store and render Django templates from models. Since it is not a standard, I am wondering what are the advantages (or disadvantages if that's the case) of file based templates.

Reading though the documentation, I have seen that it is recommended to actually cache templates and models as much as possible for best performance, so why would it not be recommended to store templates in the database? It seems very convenient to me that in doing so pages can be edited from the admin panel (where you can add a code editor), which, along with the rest framework and a front end framework synergize very well.

From my research, the template tags and template language seem to work and the context can be passed in a view as well. the only thing I cannot figure out is the {include .. } tag, as it does not seem to point to a view. (although a custom tag cam be made to have this function)

Can such a setup be used in production? or are there security/performance/other concerns?

Comment: It sounds almost as if you are talking about a CMS, editing the webpage templates from the front side. Django is certainly not a CMS, and not intended as such: it is a lower layer, hence this functionality does not exist in Django on purpose: to limit the functionality (which avoids it becoming a catch-all-can-do-everything-monostrosity).

Comment: Not realy, but in this regard django is kind of bad at front end stuff, so you have to outsource it to a js framework. In this setup, everything is very static, which is very inconvenient if you want to change some colors or fonts while already in production. And you and up building a costume CMS anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended because templates are the developer's responsibility, not the site admin's.

Otherwise, there's not much performance difference between reading files directly from filesystem and from database.

One drawback of this approach is you don't get revision history (using git, mercurial etc). Sure, you can implement something similar to save the revisions in the database, but then why not use the better tools which already exist?

There's a Django `flatpages` app which lets you save HTML content in database. But the purpose of the app is to allow site admins to edit HTML content, such as information for an "About Us" page, because writing this info is not a developer's responsibility.